# Travel from Tanger MED to Tetouan

Tags: buses, morocco, tangier

Is there some web page where we can find Buses in Morocco? We are searching for some Bus from Tanger MED to Tetouan but we found nothing.

Or do you know how to get from Tanger MED (port) to Tetouan?

Could you give us an advice?

Answer (score 2):

You can find the different options that you have [here](http://www.ctm.ma).

The web is in French but it's easy to get what you want. It also gives you the choice of paying with an international credit card in your usual currency (but you have to check the corresponding box).

Today (9/9) there are three different buses and it takes between 45 min and 1 h 15 min depending on the one you choose. The price is 20 or 25 dirhams.

Comment: We checked that but we found only from Tanger or Tanger GR to Tetouan. Both of Tanger and Tanger GR destinations are probably in Tanger city, not in Tanger MED, aren't they? Thank you.